# Parent Key Column Type Change in Many-to-Many Mapping

Tags: .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, mapping, many-to-many

I have a join table where the original table is a numeric type and the join table key column is a string type.  Legacy decision that I am trying to avoid having to change to minimize the risk to the scope of work.

```
HasManyToMany<Attachment>(x => x.Attachments)
  .Table("ObjectAttachments")
  .ParentKeyColumn("ObjectId")
  .ChildKeyColumn("AttachmentId")
  .Fetch.Select()
  .LazyLoad()
  .AsBag();
```

The owning class uses a long (numeric) type for the identifier, while the join table uses a string type for the object identifier.  How could I map this for it to change the data type on the fly?  Is there something I can use to intercept and do the conversion?

Perhaps I can open up the discussion by providing a bit more background.  The table relationship can be viewed as such:

Equipment -(r1)- ObjectAttachments -(r2)- Attachments

- r1 is defined by **Equipment**.Id = **ObjectAttachments**.Object_Id AND **ObjectAttachments**.Class = 'Equipment'
- r2 is defined by **ObjectAttachments**.Attachment_Id = **Attachment**.Attachment_Id

The thing that is throwing me for a loop is **Equipment**.Id is an **integer** data type and **ObjectAttachments**.Object_Id is a **string**.

**UPDATE**: Here is how I have proceeded for now - I created a seperate repository for the attachments and created a map that brings in the join table.  The repository requires that I convert the equipment identifier to a string.  It's not what I was hoping for but it works for now.  Here's what that map looks like:

```
Table("Attachments");
Id(x => x.Id);
Map(x => x.Name);
Map(x => x.Description);
Map(x => x.MimeType);
Map(x => x.Size);
Map(x => x.Date);
Map(x => x.Content).LazyLoad();
Join("ObjectAttachments", join =>
    {
        join.KeyColumn("Id");
        join.Map(x => x.ObjectId);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to add an extra column to the table with the string id with a formula to return the string id cast to the correct numeric type.
This constrains the problem with the database to the database rather than letting it bleed into the code.